Unable to send mail using PhpMailer and Office365
I am trying to send mail using PhpMailer and Office365 and I can't seem to get it working.
I keep getting this:
2024-05-23 08:32:26 Connection: opening to smtp.office365.com:587, timeout=300, options=array()
2024-05-23 08:32:26 Connection: opened
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "220 VI1PR06CA0212.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 23 May 2024 08:32:24 +0000"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 VI1PR06CA0212.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 23 May 2024 08:32:24 +0000
2024-05-23 08:32:26 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "250-VI1PR06CA0212.outlook.office365.com Hello [188.27.92.218]"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 157286400"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "250-DSN"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "250-STARTTLS"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "250-BINARYMIME"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "250-CHUNKING"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "250 SMTPUTF8"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-VI1PR06CA0212.outlook.office365.com Hello [188.27.92.218]250-SIZE 157286400250-PIPELINING250-DSN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-STARTTLS250-8BITMIME250-BINARYMIME250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2024-05-23 08:32:26 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
2024-05-23 08:32:26 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "250-VI1PR06CA0212.outlook.office365.com Hello [188.27.92.218]"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 157286400"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "250-DSN"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "250-BINARYMIME"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "250-CHUNKING"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "250 SMTPUTF8"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-VI1PR06CA0212.outlook.office365.com Hello [188.27.92.218]250-SIZE 157286400250-PIPELINING250-DSN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2250-8BITMIME250-BINARYMIME250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2024-05-23 08:32:26 Auth method requested: UNSPECIFIED
2024-05-23 08:32:26 Auth methods available on the server: LOGIN,XOAUTH2
2024-05-23 08:32:26 Requested auth method not available:
2024-05-23 08:32:26 Auth method selected: LOGIN
2024-05-23 08:32:26 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2024-05-23 08:32:26 CLIENT -> SERVER: xxx
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SMTP INBOUND: "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6"
2024-05-23 08:32:26 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2024-05-23 08:32:26 CLIENT -> SERVER: xxx
2024-05-23 08:32:31 SMTP INBOUND: "535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the user credentials were incorrect. [VI1PR06CA0212.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com 2024-05-23T08:32:30.734Z 08DC7AAF1DD95EEB]"
2024-05-23 08:32:31 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the user credentials were incorrect. [VI1PR06CA0212.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com 2024-05-23T08:32:30.734Z 08DC7AAF1DD95EEB]
2024-05-23 08:32:31 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the user credentials were incorrect. [VI1PR06CA0212.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com 2024-05-23T08:32:30.734Z 08DC7AAF1DD95EEB]
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2024-05-23 08:32:31 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2024-05-23 08:32:31 SMTP INBOUND: "221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel"
2024-05-23 08:32:31 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel
2024-05-23 08:32:31 Connection: closed
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Or this:
2024-05-23 08:57:31 Connection: opening to smtp.office365.com:587, timeout=300, options=array()
2024-05-23 08:57:31 Connection: opened
2024-05-23 08:57:31 SMTP INBOUND: "220 VI1PR07CA0239.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 23 May 2024 08:57:30 +0000"
2024-05-23 08:57:31 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 VI1PR07CA0239.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 23 May 2024 08:57:30 +0000
2024-05-23 08:57:31 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2024-05-23 08:57:31 SMTP INBOUND: "250-VI1PR07CA0239.outlook.office365.com Hello [188.27.92.218]"
2024-05-23 08:57:31 SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 157286400"
2024-05-23 08:57:31 SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
2024-05-23 08:57:31 SMTP INBOUND: "250-DSN"
2024-05-23 08:57:31 SMTP INBOUND: "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2024-05-23 08:57:31 SMTP INBOUND: "250-STARTTLS"
2024-05-23 08:57:31 SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2024-05-23 08:57:31 SMTP INBOUND: "250-BINARYMIME"
2024-05-23 08:57:31 SMTP INBOUND: "250-CHUNKING"
2024-05-23 08:57:31 SMTP INBOUND: "250 SMTPUTF8"
2024-05-23 08:57:31 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-VI1PR07CA0239.outlook.office365.com Hello [188.27.92.218]250-SIZE 157286400250-PIPELINING250-DSN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-STARTTLS250-8BITMIME250-BINARYMIME250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2024-05-23 08:57:31 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2024-05-23 08:57:31 SMTP INBOUND: "220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready"
2024-05-23 08:57:31 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
2024-05-23 08:57:31 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2024-05-23 08:57:32 SMTP INBOUND: "250-VI1PR07CA0239.outlook.office365.com Hello [188.27.92.218]"
2024-05-23 08:57:32 SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 157286400"
2024-05-23 08:57:32 SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
2024-05-23 08:57:32 SMTP INBOUND: "250-DSN"
2024-05-23 08:57:32 SMTP INBOUND: "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2024-05-23 08:57:32 SMTP INBOUND: "250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2"
2024-05-23 08:57:32 SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2024-05-23 08:57:32 SMTP INBOUND: "250-BINARYMIME"
2024-05-23 08:57:32 SMTP INBOUND: "250-CHUNKING"
2024-05-23 08:57:32 SMTP INBOUND: "250 SMTPUTF8"
2024-05-23 08:57:32 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-VI1PR07CA0239.outlook.office365.com Hello [188.27.92.218]250-SIZE 157286400250-PIPELINING250-DSN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2250-8BITMIME250-BINARYMIME250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2024-05-23 08:57:32 Auth method requested: UNSPECIFIED
2024-05-23 08:57:32 Auth methods available on the server: LOGIN,XOAUTH2
2024-05-23 08:57:32 Requested auth method not available:
2024-05-23 08:57:32 Auth method selected: LOGIN
2024-05-23 08:57:32 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2024-05-23 08:57:32 SMTP INBOUND: "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6"
2024-05-23 08:57:32 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2024-05-23 08:57:32 CLIENT -> SERVER: x
2024-05-23 08:57:32 SMTP INBOUND: "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6"
2024-05-23 08:57:32 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2024-05-23 08:57:32 CLIENT -> SERVER: xxx
2024-05-23 08:57:37 SMTP INBOUND: "535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, user is locked by your organization's security defaults policy. Contact your administrator. [VI1PR07CA0239.eurprd07.prod.outlook.com 2024-05-23T08:57:36.203Z 08DC79F28D95D3F2]"
2024-05-23 08:57:37 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, user is locked by your organization's security defaults policy. Contact your administrator. [VI1PR07CA0239.eurprd07.prod.outlook.com 2024-05-23T08:57:36.203Z 08DC79F28D95D3F2]
2024-05-23 08:57:37 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, user is locked by your organization's security defaults policy. Contact your administrator. [VI1PR07CA0239.eurprd07.prod.outlook.com 2024-05-23T08:57:36.203Z 08DC79F28D95D3F2]
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2024-05-23 08:57:37 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2024-05-23 08:57:37 SMTP INBOUND: "221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel"
2024-05-23 08:57:37 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel
2024-05-23 08:57:37 Connection: closed
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

I enabled SMTP in Office, I also enabled App Passwords and I am using an app password for this. Disabling Security Defaults is not really an option, since that implies disabling it for all email accounts, not just one.
I do believe this has something to do with Office365 settings but in case I missed something, here is the code:
function sendClientMail($submitValue, $mail)
{
    $product = $submitValue['product'];

    try {
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->AuthType   = 'LOGIN';
        $mail->Host       = 'smtp.office365.com';
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
        $mail->Username   = '';
        $mail->Password   = '';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Port       = 587;

        $mail->setFrom('', '');
        $mail->addAddress('', '');

        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = "Welcome to " . returnApp($product);
        $mail->Body    = returnHTMLMailBody($product);
        $mail->AltBody = returnPlainTextMailBody($product);

        $mail->send();

        header("location:index.php?ok=" . $product);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
}

I tried AuthType  LOGIN, PLAIN and CRAM-MD5 and SMTPSecure tls, ssl and STARTSSL, all combinations with the same result.
Any suggestions?

SMTPSecure should be ssl or tls, not STARTSSL, and you have not set AuthType at all, which is why it's saying Auth method requested: UNSPECIFIED

@Synchro Thanks. STARTSSL was suggested in a few posts so I tried it as well. I changed to tls and AuthType LOGIN and PLAIN but I get the same error. Specifically, the second one.

The second set of errors there looks to be correct – PHPMailer is using the right settings with LOGIN, but it seems that Office doesn't like your credentials. I suggest asking Office support for help as their rules for this kind of auth are very complicated. BTW with SMTPDebug = 4, encoded passwords (easily decoded) are revealed, so it might be a good idea to revoke those credentials and issue new ones.

@Synchro Thanks. Our Office settings are good since we are using the same mail and credentials on another website and we tested it on another host. We went through host's support and it appears they don't allow SMTP access for other mail accounts that are not running through their servers. Our account is not found in their list, hence the wrong credentials. Or so they said. Does it make sense?

@Synchro Thanks for the tip and edit. Will do.
